# How to generate a Python exe file to execute in a Java program?

Tags: python, java

I Generate an .exe file from a Python script with the following command `pyinstaller test.py --onefile --windowed`. Then I run the .exe file from the `dist` folder or from any other location and it works perfect.

The problem is that I am trying to run this .exe file from a Java program. When I try to run it from Java, a pop up appears with the following error:

```
Failed to execute script 'test' due to unhandled exception [Errno 22] invalid argument:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 5, <in module>
```

This is my python code:

```
from docx2pdf import convert

input = "C:\\Users\\myUser\\test.docx"
output = "C:\\Users\\myUser\\file.pdf"
convert(input,output)
```

I try to run the python exe file with Java as:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\myUser\\test.exe", null, new File("C:\\Users\\myUser\\"));
```

Also I try with the following commands:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\myUser\\test.exe");
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(file.getAbsolutePath());
processBuilder.directory(file.getParentFile());

try {
    processBuilder.start();
} catch(IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The exe file works fine when run manually but fails when run from Java. I really need to execute the python exe file from the Java code, because I want to execute my Java app in other computers without python installed.

Comment: I'm not sure Python will handle being passed a null environment.  You should try the one-argument version of `exec`.  You are aware that `docx2pdf` requires that a copy of Microsoft Word is installed?  It launches Word to do the conversion.

Comment: yes, I know. But as I mention, if I execute the .exe file manually it works perfectly, the problem only occurs when run the .exe file from Java

Comment: Did you read the first part of my comment?  You should try `Runtime.getrunTime().exec("C:\\Users\\myUser\\test.exe");`.  Your call is passing a null pointer for the environment, not a zero-length array, which would be normal.  That's my current suspicion.

Comment: Yes, I read your comment. I try with your suggestion but also get the same error. If you read my question I also mention that I try with the ProcessBuilder class, but the error is the same.